# Deleting items from a list with a less than operator

Tags: python, string, list

I am working on a program for a class which has us build a craigslist type of program.

```
myStr=[]
b = "bike"
ans = True
while ans:
    print "1. Add an item"
    print "2. Find an item"
    print "3. Print the message board"
    print "4. Quit"
    choice = input("Enter your selection: ")
    if choice == 1:
        itemType = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c: ")
        itemCost = input("Enter the item cost: ")
        myStr.append([itemType,itemCost])
    if choice == 2:
        itemType = raw_input("Enter the item type-b,m,d,t,c: ")
        maximum = input("Enter the maximum item cost: ")
        print maximum
    if choice == 3:
        print myStr
    if choice == 4:
        break
```

Fairly easy to read what's going on here but I am missing a crucial part which is deleting entries from myStr. I tried using a for loop but it did not work. What I need it to do is delete the first entry that meets this criteria.
`if maximum > itemCost then delete the first item in the list`.
I can't wrap my brain around it so any help would be great.

Also, any other advice to improve my code is welcome!

Comment: There are ways to delete from a list, but they are basically ugly because lists are not good data structures for this kind of problems. Consider using a dictionary.

Comment: For code review see [codereview.se].

Comment: Write some new code just to experiment with what you are trying to achieve in two or three lines of code. Then your question can be about a single problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something extracting the list of items whose cost is greater than maximum and then removing those items from your list. List comprehension is great at it.

```
max_cost = 3
myStr = [['Item1', 2], ['Item2', 3], ['Item3', 4]]
to_remove = [item for item in myStr if item[1] > max_cost]
for item in to_remove:
    myStr.remove(item)
```

You could try with something like that.